# Passing ggplot through a function and referencing an argument

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using ggplot2 within a function and trying to create average lines for the y-axis. I'm running into trouble seemingly because the variable that defines the y-axis is one of the function args, and I can't call it directly within ggplot.

```
library(ggplot2)


west <- data.frame(
  spend = sample(50:100,50,replace=T),
  trials = sample(100:200,50,replace=T),
  courts = sample(25:50,50,replace=T),
  country = sample(c("usa","canada","uk"),50,replace = T)
)
```

Here's a basic version of the function I'm working with:

```
ggfun <- function(data, xvar, yvar) {

  newplot <- ggplot(data=west, aes_string(x=xvar, y=yvar)) +
    geom_point(shape=21, fill="blue") + 

  newplot      
}
```

and calling that as below works:

```
ggfun(west, "spend", "trials")
```

But when I try to add in geom_hline, I get an error:

```
ggfun <- function(data, xvar, yvar) {

  newplot <- ggplot(data=west, aes_string(x=xvar, y=yvar)) +
    geom_point(shape=21, fill="blue") + 
    geom_hline(yintercept=mean(yvar))

  newplot  
}

ggfun(west, "spend", "trials")

Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(data$yvar) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_hline).
```

Is it not possible to call data this way within a function using ggplot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`aes_string` substitutes the whole string, not just the var. You can create the right string using `paste`:

```
library(ggplot2)
west <- data.frame(
  spend = sample(50:100,50,replace=T),
  trials = sample(100:200,50,replace=T),
  courts = sample(25:50,50,replace=T),
  country = sample(c("usa","canada","uk"),50,replace = T)
)
ggfun <- function(data, xvar, yvar) {
  newplot <- ggplot(data=data, aes_string(x=xvar, y=yvar)) +
    geom_point(shape=21, fill="blue") + 
    geom_hline(aes_string(yintercept = paste0('mean(', yvar, ')')))

  newplot  
}
ggfun(west, "spend", "trials")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`yvar` is a string, it works exactly as if you were doing this, not in a function:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = mean("mpg"))
Warning messages:
1: In mean.default("mpg") :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_hline).
```

I'd recommend pre-computing the mean, that way you can pass a value to the `yintercept`:

```
ggfun <- function(data, xvar, yvar) {
  mean_yvar = mean(data[[yvar]])
  newplot <- ggplot(data = west, aes_string(x = xvar, y = yvar)) +
    geom_point(shape=21, fill="blue") + 
    geom_hline(yintercept = mean_yvar)

  newplot  
}

ggfun(west, "spend", "trials")
# works fine
```